# rosdep install sr_control_gui

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i trying to run

```
rosdep install sr_control_gui
```

but when i wrote that the terminal gives me :

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource sr_control_gui
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
```

How cN I INATll ir, i'm using ros fuerte on ubuntu 12.04, thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48301/rosdep-install-sr_control_gui/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like `sr_control_gui` is not in your ROS package path. Have a look at the [overlay page](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) for information on how to set up overlays and download packages.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0